# Статистика сетевой активности процесса

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, сеть, трафик

Никак не могу найти возможности определить сетевую активность процесса(ов), сколько принял и сколько отправил байт, хотя монитор ресурсов Windows это легко делает. Есть хоть какие примеры по данной тематике (можно примеры и WinAPI, Basic)?

Comment: Performance counter'ы посмотрите. Пишут что там есть нужная информация, но сам не смотрел.

Comment: Нужно именно по каждому процессу?

Comment: Да по каждому, пробовал pcap, но там очень много не нужных вычислений происходит, как следствие загрузка процессора на уровне

Comment: Performance counter не чего толкового не нашел, может плохо ищу

Comment: @SergD29 да, как-то по ним плохо ищется... Но есть в MSDN пример вывода всех счетчиков с описаниями. Может найдет нужный.

Comment: PerformanceCounter не умеет показывать использование сети отдельным процессом. Во всяком случае стандартный интерфейс системного монитора не дает такой возможности. Но можно посмотреть статистику всего ввода-вывода процесса.

Answer (score 2):

Для отслеживания событий передачи данных по сети в Windows существует механизм Event Tracing. Чтобы использовать его в .NET, можно подключить библиотеку [TraceEvent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/) и обрабатывать события *TcpIpRecv*/*TcpIpSend* провайдера *Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Network*, содержащие размер переданных или полученных байт:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Parsers;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Session;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static TraceEventSession m_EtwSession;
        static void ThreadProc()
        {                       

            int pid = Process.GetProcessesByName("Program")[0].Id;            

            using (m_EtwSession = new TraceEventSession(KernelTraceEventParser.KernelSessionName))
            {
                m_EtwSession.StopOnDispose = true;
                m_EtwSession.EnableKernelProvider(KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.NetworkTCPIP);

                m_EtwSession.Source.Kernel.TcpIpRecv += data =>
                {
                    if (data.ProcessID == pid)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Received: " + data.size.ToString() + " bytes ");
                    }      
                };

                m_EtwSession.Source.Kernel.TcpIpSend += data =>
                {
                    if (data.ProcessID == pid)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sent: " + data.size.ToString() + " bytes ");
                    }                    
                };

                m_EtwSession.Source.Process();                   
            }

        }

        public static void Main(string[] argv)
        {
            Thread th = new Thread(ThreadProc);
            th.IsBackground = true;
            th.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop tracing...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            m_EtwSession.Dispose();            
        }        

    }

}
```